# Do Theoretical Computer Science Conferences Accepts Survey Papers?

Tags: cs-theory

I am a Ph.D. student in Theoretical Computer Science (TCS). If I want to publish a survey paper, can I send that to a conference instead of a journal? Is that allowed?

I am asking this because the quality of research in TCS is judged mostly by the top conferences (like SODA, STOC, and FOCS).

Comment: Hi Inuyasha! Welcome to [cseducators.se]! We mostly take questions about teaching computer science, so this question about more general CS academia / studying CS would be off topic for us, which is why it's been closed.

Comment: @thesecretmaster I understand. I should have posted the question on Academia.SE. I did not post it there since I thought that the question is very specific to my field so it might get answered there. But I got a helpful answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That is up to the individual conference. All of them have web sites that will explain what they prefer. I'm skeptical a bit, however.

But, many such CS conferences have different "tracks" and different associated activities. You might find a better welcome at one of these. For example, some have an associated "educator's track" that might welcome something like this. But you need to check individually. The program chair (or conference chair) will probably respond to an email if you don't find what you are looking for online. Most such people have email addresses that are easy to discover even when not listed on the conference site.

Theoretical conferences will, of course, prefer papers that extend the theory.